# CMakeList Exclude sub directories of INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: c++, cmake, subdirectory, cmakelists-options

I'm developing a C++ app under Ubuntu and I target Windows system.
I'm compiling with mingw and to get IDE code completion I use

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include")
```

The problem is I got a lot of stuff inside this include directory and I only want to Work with STL and Windows API.
Is there a way to exclude the sub directories I want for example

```
"exclude(${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}/curl"
```

This would make my IDE much faster.
I hope your answers, thanks.

Comment: There may be better answers than mine. However, I think you should just use `include_directories()` or `target_include_directories()` if you want to be granular about your includes.

Comment: Hi @user3389943,
I already tried to use `target_include_directories()` and it's not really helping because I need to include `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` and not `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/curl`

Comment: Variable [CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH.html) doesn't add include directories by itself. It affects only on searching performed by `find_path` and `find_file` commands. And only results of these commands are used as include directories. If you want to deliberately affect on specific `find_path`/`find_file` calls, then you need to hint using other ways (not via setting `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` globally).

Comment: But when actual include directory is added, it is used for all `#include` directives resolution, would be it `#include <vector.h>` or `#include <curl/curl.h>`. You cannot make include directory usable only for the first include but not for the second one.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev,
Thanks for helping, so if I understand I should only include the headers I want and not a global path ?